# Laravel Mix and SASS changing font directory

Tags: laravel, sass, webpack, webpack-2, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Mix to output SASS files.

In my font definitions I'm configuring them so that when the CSS is output it will point to files such as `public/assets/fnt/font-name/filename.ext` but the processor changes the output so that it will instead point to `public/fonts/filename.ext`. Is there a way to stop it from changing the output paths?

It makes little sense to me that it would do something like this by default.

**Edit**

I've seen that the defaults they're using in Mix are the culprit:

```
module.exports.module = {
    rules: [
        // ...
        {
            test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
                publicPath: '/'
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I've tried using `null-loader` instead of `file-loader` but instead it causes it to fail because it can't find the files in `node_modules` which is not where it should be looking in the first place.

Removing the rule in question results in a flood of errors from trying to open and evaluate the font files in question:

```
 error  in ./public/assets/fnt/fanfare-jf/fanfare-jf.ttf

Module parse failed: DIRECTORY\public\assets\fnt\fanfare-jf\fanfare-jf.ttf Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap&precision=8!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 6:2525-2590
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

I can at least add `emitFiles: false` to `options` to prevent it from making copies of the file, but the paths are still being altered.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this question as Webpack-2? The config structure is going to be considerably different dealing with loaders and options.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with the following configuration to at least get it to a working state.

```
let assetDir = 'assets/build';

mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = `${assetDir}/${mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts}`;
mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.images = `${assetDir}/${mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.images}`;

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', `public/${assetDir}/css`)
   .js('resources/js/app.js', `public/${assetDir}/js`);
```

**Updated:**

In newer versions this has been made customizable via `mix.options()` and can be adjusted as below:

```
let assetDir = 'assets/build';

mix.options({
    fileLoaderDirs: {
        images: `${assetDir}/img`,
        fonts: `${assetDir}/fonts`
    }
});

// adjust build commands accordingly, for example:
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', `public/${assetDir}/js`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you got is the intended behaviour due to your configuration.

You are using this configuration to load the file:

```
        options: {
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
            publicPath: '/'
        }
```

Which says use the publicPath as `public` and create a file with the name `fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]` and webpack knows about what these symbols `'/', '.', '?'` in the name do.

**It just looks for the `fonts` directory and if there is no any fonts directory it creates a new one and place the files into that directory.**

So, you need to use this configuration for your folder structure:

```
options: {
    name: 'assets/fnt/font-name/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

This should work for your configuration.

More on `file-loader` configuration:

> https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#filename-templates

**Edit:**

**Since `Laravel Mix` uses `Webpack` in it's background and Webpack doesn't have any knowledge of the fonts file when there is no any appropriate loader added to the configuration**. So, the error:

```
Module parse failed: DIRECTORY\public\assets\fnt\fanfare-jf\fanfare-jf.ttf Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

is occurred.

You need to tell the Webpack to load the fonts to your desired directory and the fonts linked in your `SASS` file will be linked by the `Webpack` without any more configurations.

Comment: The configuration I've listed was foisted onto me by the defaults in Laravel Mix. I don't want it to copy the files or anything _at all_. The configuration given leads to it re-copying the files. I don't care what it wants to do. I know the files already exist at the location I've given it. I want it to completely leave me alone.

Comment: So, in my view you don't want to use `Laravel Mix`?

Comment: If you define your view as "not wanting to use one tiny component means you don't want to use the whole thing at all" then yes. In this case, I have literally spent all day from 10 to 23:30 trying to get it to simply leave my URLs alone.

Comment: If you don't want to use the file-loader to load your fonts file then you could simply remove the rules `{ test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/, .... }` that include your `fonts `. This is what i understood by your scenario.

Comment: If I remove the rule it tries to load and evaluate the files referenced in the CSS directives, and fails to build.

Comment: Could you show me your errors? Which was causing when you removed the loader rule

Comment: @DissidentRage Added some information for your knowledge, and you don't need to worry about linking the fonts from your SASS file, Laravel Mix does it for you. But you need to add the configurations as it is must for Webpack.

Comment: I _don't want it to do it for me_ because the files are not necessarily organized in a way that can be represented using the path variables provided. I want it to just roll over the URLs and give me what's already there. It should not presume I need it to hold my hand by default because it now limits me to doing things their way. I just need it to be a good SASS and Javascript processor/compiler.

Comment: Then i am unable to solve your issue. Hope someone could help you.